# How to list the releases of a repository?

Tags: github, github-api

Can the GitHub API return a list of repository's releases, along with the date each release was created?

The "releases" API is acting unexpectedly, e.g. 0 releases for rails:

```
>> curl https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/releases
[

]
```

Additionally, is there a way to know if a release is alpha, beta or stable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think you can specifically do releases. But you can get tags.

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/tags`

Source: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags

**Edit:**

They released the releases API today.

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/

Comment: Tags look good enough, though they seem to be [sorted by name in the api](https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/tags) vs. [sorted by date in the web interface](https://github.com/rails/rails/tags)

Comment: I also need the tag's creation date. I guess the way achieve this is to query the tag's commit by sha? e.g. [this commit](https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/commits/a96df04aac00fb2b7d91978c24741100230a50d4)

Answer (score 17):

This question is old, however Google still lead me here and the answers are dated. So for any others that find themselves here:

GitHub has sense added a releases endpoint: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases

An example of getting one (via `curl`):

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/releases
```

Answer (score 1):

Releases on GitHub can have assets attached to them. You can link to each of them, however, you can't link to the assets of the latest release.

You have two options:

Leverage a shell command and pipe the results to parse the response from github:
example:

```sh
curl https://api.github.com/repos/direnv/direnv/releases/latest \
| jq -r '.assets[] | select(.browser_download_url | contains("linux-amd64")) | .browser_download_url'
```

*response*

```sh
https://github.com/direnv/direnv/releases/download/v2.28.0/direnv.linux-amd64
```

Option 2: Use a 3rd Party service like gitreleases.dev

> With a Git Releases link, you can skip updating your README or public website with a new download link whenever a new release has been done. Instead, it will always point to the right location.

https://gitreleases.dev/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `/releases` endpoint for repositories (yet?). The only way to vaguely get anything like that is to use @kristenmills answer of listing tags. That's how releases are currently generated on GitHub's site and that's exactly how you can determine what has been released.