# How can I use github api to get all tags or releases for a project?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to know how to use the github-api to get all the current releases or tags for a project.  I have seen the [documentation for tags in github-api](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) but I don't see a way to list all tags or list all releases but only list a specific tag by :sha.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list the releases of a repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384873/how-to-list-the-releases-of-a-repository)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's possible, but the documentation is perhaps not in the place you'd expect it to be.

http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/

> You can also request a sub-namespace. For example, to get all the tag
>   references, you can call:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/tags
```

Answer (score 13):

Note: for the [releases specifically](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) of a GitHub repo, you now have ([since Sept. 25th, 2013](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-09-25-releases-api/)), an [api to list all the releases](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository):

### List releases for a repository

- Users with push access to the repository will receive all releases (i.e., published releases and draft releases).
- Users with pull access will receive published releases only.

  ```
  GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
  ```

> Response

```
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999

[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/v1.0.0",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets{?name}",
    "id": 1,
    "tag_name": "v1.0.0",
    "target_commitish": "master",
    "name": "v1.0.0",
    "body": "Description of the release",
    "draft": false,
    "prerelease": false,
    "created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
    "published_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z"
  }
]
```

### Get a single release

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the limit cap? I'm only getting the last X releases.

Comment: @NickeManarin I don't think so, considering this should be limited by pagination rules: see https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/.

Comment: Ahh, I just had to append `?per_page=50` at the end of it. Thanks.

Comment: There may also be a `Link` header to support pagination. That will need to be parsed to get the `next` url.

Answer (score 12):

This morning I received an answer to this same question that I posted to the github support team.  Not sure how I can attribute the answer correctly but here is their response.

> **Quote from Ivan Žužak of Github support team**
>
> You can get a list of all tags for a repository using this API call:
>
> http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags
>
> So, for example, making the following cURL request will return the list of tags for the  libgit2/libgit2 repository:
>
> $ curl -v "https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2/tags"

Comment: Take in mind that `:repo/git/refs/tags` may give you a different result than `:repo/tags`. That's what happened in my case.

Comment: The main problem with /tags is I cannot get the latest version for some repos. For example, https://api.github.com/repos/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/latest returns value, https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/latest also returns but https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo/releases/latest returns "Not found", https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo/tags/latest as well. In my case I need created releases for repo, not only tags. Is there any way around this?

Comment: This only lists the latest couple of tags, not all of them.

Comment: missing tags are related to the default api response paging
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#pagination

Answer (score 5):

In v4, graphQL, you can use this query https://developer.github.com/v4/object/tag/

```
query {
  repository(owner: "onmyway133", name: "Scale") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 2) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: in GQL, you can use a more specific `refPrefix`. Let's say you have two types of tags: `foo/...` and `bar/...`, you can use `refs/tags/foo/` to only show `foo/` tags. The `refPrefix` must end with `/`. (which corresponds to how git stores tags on disk: `foo/...` tags will be in `foo/` subfolder of `.git/refs/tags/`. If you use tags like `foo-...` and `bar-...`, it's good to rename them to use `/` as separator for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

The API call to get all tags as **JSON** list is:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/tags
```

Example: https://api.github.com/repos/alacritty/alacritty/tags

The response is sorted: more recent tags come first.

To get releases change `/tags` to `/releases`. And don't add a trailing slash `/` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

This will list all your Releases (tags) on Github.  Might need to tweek the `grep` part depending on your tag naming conventions:

```
curl -s 'https://github.com/username/reponame/tags/'|grep -o "$Version v[0-9].[0-9][0-9]"
```

If cutting-n-pasting the URL from the "clone repo" section, remember to chop the`.git` off at the end of the address when constructing above URL-  HTH- Terrence Houlahan

Comment: No, this will only list the last couple of tags.