# Cannot get releases for a Repo with the Github API

Tags: github-api

I am experiencing problems with the Github API when I try to get the releases for a public repo. I've made several request to /repos/:owner/:repo/releases (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) and I'm not able to obtain the releases of a repo, except when I request for the releases of one of my repos and I had created the releases via Github API (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release).

For example, this GET request to the server returns an empty body and a 200 status:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/releases
```

I make the request with the Authorization header (Authorization: token {MY_TOKEN}), specifying a token mine with gist, repo and user permisions.

Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong or what is the best approach to retrieve the releases of a repo?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18999865/1024794 if you want not published releases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot request **non-published** releases. So if the request come with an empty response body then there is no published release under that repository i.e. *github.com/jquery/jquery* don't have one.

In order to get a *JSON* feed containing a list of a (owner/repo) releases using the Github Release API endpoint *"/repos/:owner/:repo/releases"* there must be published releases in that repo.

This is how a published release looks like:

[image]

And here you can try to request a release on a repo of mine where I already published a release version: https://api.github.com/repos/wisebrains/wise-archetypes/releases

Comment: so if there is no published release, then how can i get the release list info just like i visist the release page ?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases there are no published releases, but you can still [list tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) by using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/tags` endpoint.

For example:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/twigphp/twig/tags
```

Note that this call will only return the 30 latest tags.

Comment: yeah this is the answer, usually when it's a mirror repo, github won't have list of releases